# Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IModal>'

Tags: typescript

I keep getting this message eventhough I think I already did what I needed to get rid of it. This is how this piece of code looks like.

```
const toggleModal: boolean = useSelector<IRootState>(state => state.toggleModal) 
// Here I get "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'boolean'" when I hover toggleModal
```

[...]

```
useEffect(() => {
   setModal(toggleModal) // Here I get the message
 }, [toggleModal])
```

Any idea on how can I fix this?

EDIT:

This is my useState:

```
const [modal, setModal] = useState<IModal>({modal: false});
```

And this is how I initialized the `IRootState` interface:

```
interface IRootState {
  state: object;
  toggleModal: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useSelector()` doesn't return a boolean, so you can't assign it to a boolean.

You could try this:

```js
// leave the type out
const toggleModal = useSelector<IRootState>(state => state.toggleModal);
```

Or you could do it like this:

```js
const toggleModal = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.toggleModal);
```

Comment: Thank you. Doing this I get rid of the problem at `const toggleModal`. But I still get the problem in the useEffect, where, when I hove over `toggleModal` I get this message: `Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IModal>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(prevState: IModal) => IModal'`

Comment: How did you initiate your state?

Comment: Doing that I get this error: `Argument of type '[{ modal: boolean; }, Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ modal: boolean; }>>]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ modal: boolean; }>'`

Comment: I edited the post to show how I initialized the IRootState interface

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment, I meant to say: `const [modal, setModal] = useState();`, could you try this out. You can leave the useSelector like in my answer.